# How to toggle external CSS on button click

Tags: php, jquery, css, magento, buttonclick

I am facing one problem, I want to do something like this:

I want to toggle the EXTERNAL CSS when user is click on toggle button.

There are 5 different pages;  there are:

1. Header
2. Footer
3. Main page
4. Contact us
5. About us

and I have 2 external style sheets:

1. style.css
2. style1.css

By default style.css is loaded.

Now when I click on toggle button  then `style1.css` has to load, and when again click on toggle button `style.css` has to load and visa verse. I want to do something like this.

Is there anyone have an Idea regarding this. Please help me out!

CSS is loaded on header so when I click on toggle button I want to apply new `style.css`.

the problem i am facing is that when i am clicking on any other page at that time the default css is set but in my case i don't want that By default style.css is loaded now when user click on button style1.css is loaded now when user again click on button style.css is loaded when click again style1.css loaded and again style.css loaded i want to do something like this and this changes should be there for whole website of main! thnx for your valuable reply and wait for more accurate –

Answer (score 2):

By doing something like this:

```
$("a").click(function () {
    $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css" type="text/css" />');
});
```

See [Applying stylesheets dynamically with jQuery](http://www.rickardnilsson.net/post/2008/08/02/Applying-stylesheets-dynamically-with-jQuery.aspx)

[**DEMO**](http://www.rickardnilsson.net/demo/dynamiccss/dynamicCss.html)

Comment: Hello All i am tried all of your code but the problem i am facing is that when i am clicking on any other page at that time the default css is set but in my case i don't want that By default style.css is loaded now when  user click on button style1.css is loaded now when user again click on button style.css is loaded when click again style1.css loaded and again style.css loaded  i want to do something like this and this changes should be there for whole website of main! thnx for your valuable reply and wait for more accurate

Answer (score 1):

See [Stylesheet Switcher jQuery](http://lesson8.blogspot.in/2012/07/stylesheet-switcher-jquery.html)

```
<script src="script/jquery-1.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery.cookie.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        if ($.cookie("css")) {
            $("link").attr("href", $.cookie("css"));
        }
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#nav li a").click(function () {
                $("link").attr("href", $(this).attr('rel'));
                $.cookie("css", $(this).attr('rel'), { expires: 365, path: '/' });
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
    <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="#" rel="css/metro.blue.css">Original CSS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" rel="css/metro.green.css">Larger Text</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" rel="css/metro.red.css">Something Different</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$("#btntoggle").click(function(){
          if($("LINK[href*='style.css']").lenght() > 0){
              $("LINK[href*='style.css']").remove();
              addCss(path + "style1.css");
          }else{
              $("LINK[href*='style1.css']").remove();
              addCss(path + "style.css");
         }
});


function addCss(path){
    var headID = $("head").get(0);       
    var newCss = document.createElement('LINK');
    newCss.rel = 'StyleSheet';
    newCss.type = 'text/css';
    newCss.href= path;
    newCss.media = 'screen';
    headID.appendChild(newCss);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that i've added the default style sheet in the markup, in case the user got JS disabled. So you get some kind of a fallback.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>      
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style1.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function(){   
                $("#change").click(function(){                      
                        $('head link').each(function(){
                            if($(this).attr('rel') == "stylesheet"){
                                if($(this).attr('href') == "style1.css"){
                                    $(this).attr("href","style2.css");
                                } else {
                                    $(this).attr("href","style1.css");
                                }
                            }
                        });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body> 
        <button id="change">Change</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = Mage::helper("core/url")->getCurrentUrl(); // $url contain your current url 

if(!isset($_SESSION['cssfile']) and !isset($_GET['l']))
{
    /*$urlArr = explode("?",$url);
    $tmpUrl = $urlArr[0];
    $tmpUrl .= "?";
    $andP = '';
    $i=1;
    for(;$i<count($urlArr);$i++)
    {
        $tmpUrl .= $andP.$urlArr[$i];
        $andP = '&';
    }
    if($i>1)
        $tmpUrl .= '&l=1';
    else
        $tmpUrl .= 'l=1';*/
    //$urlGet = $tmpUrl;//$url."?l=0";
    $_SESSION['cssfile'] = '1';
}

if(isset($_GET['l']) and $_GET['l']==0)
{
//      $urlGet = $url."?l=1";
    $_SESSION['cssfile'] = '0';
}
else if(isset($_GET['l']) and $_GET['l']==1)
{   
//      $urlGet = $url."?l=1";
    $_SESSION['cssfile'] = '1';
}

if(isset($_SESSION['cssfile']))
{
    $urlArr = explode("?",$url);
    $tmpUrl = $urlArr[0];
    $tmpUrl .= "?";
    $andP = '';
    $found = 0;
    //for($i=1;$i<count($urlArr);$i++)
    foreach($_GET as $key => $val)
    {
        if($key == 'l')
        {
            $found = 1;
            if($val == 1)
                $val = 0;
            else
                $val = 1;
        }
        $tmpUrl .= $andP.$key.'='.$val;
        $andP = '&';
    }
    if($found == 0 && count($_GET)>0)
        if($_SESSION['cssfile'] ==1)
            $tmpUrl .= '&l=0';
        else
            $tmpUrl .= '&l=1';
    else if($found == 0 && count($_GET)==0)
        if($_SESSION['cssfile'] ==1)
            $tmpUrl .= 'l=0';
        else
            $tmpUrl .= 'l=1';
    $urlGet = $tmpUrl;
}

/*if(isset($_SESSION['cssfile']) and $_SESSION['cssfile'] == 'styles1.css' )
{
    $_SESSION['cssfile'] = 'styles.css';
    $_SESSION['cssfile']

}
else
{
    $_SESSION['cssfile'] = 'styles1.css';
}*/
//echo '--'.$_SESSION['cssfile'];
if($_SESSION['cssfile'] ==1){
?>
 <link href="<?php echo  $this->getSkinUrl()?>css/styles1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  id="style" />
<?php }else{ ?>
    <link href="<?php echo  $this->getSkinUrl()?>css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  id="style"     />
    <?php } ?>
```